# Type passing argument 3 of 'HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]

Tags: c, pointers, stm32

I am trying to use HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit with a code that looks like this:

```c
uint8_t *pData;
pData[0]=0xF3;

if (HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, 0x40<<1, &pData, 1, 100) != HAL_OK) {...}
```

And I'm getting the following warning:

> Type passing argument 3 of 'HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit' from incompatible
>   pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead `&pData` you need to pass `pData`. Now you pass pointer to pointer and it is of course not compatible. It is also wrong.

So the function call should be:

```
if (HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, 0x40<<1, pData, 1, 100) != HAL_OK) {...}
```

Comment: Yep!
That was it
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Although you haven't shown what the definition/declaration for the `HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit` function is, it would appear (from a [quick Google search](https://os.mbed.com/users/EricLew/code/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/docs/tip/group__I2C__Exported__Functions__Group2.html)) that the third parameter should be a `uint8_t*`.

In the code you have presented, `pData` is *already* such a pointer, so you don't need to pass its address - which makes the parameter a *pointer-to-pointer*.

So, by following the given declaration, just remove the `&` from your call:

```c
if (HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, 0x40<<1, /*&*/pData, 1, 100) != HAL_OK) {...}
```